# Как вывести наибольшее число, кратное х. А то у меня выводит последнее число в матрице кратное х

Tags: c, массивы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()

{
    int mas[100][100], m, n, x, q=0, rand();
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
        printf("Количество строк и столбов в матрице: ");
        scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
        printf("Введите число: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        printf("Исходная матрица: \n");
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
                {
                    mas[i][j] = rand() %100;
                    printf("%d\t", mas[i][j]);
                    if (mas[i][j]%x == 0)
                    q = mas[i][j];
                }
    printf("\n");
        
            }
    printf("Максимальное число кратное 5: %d", q);

}
```

Comment: `q = max(mas[i][j], q)`

Comment: это вместо 'q = mas[i][j];'?

Comment: тогда компилятор выдает ошибку

Comment: то что mas не может быть в этих скобках

Comment: Ну понятное дело, Вы код выше тоже в первый раз видите? Я же указал на принципиальную ошибку. Подключите `algorithm.h`, и выражение тогда `q = std::max(mas[i][j], q)`. Но что мешает просто написать: `q = mas[i][j] > q ? mas[i][j] : q`?

Comment: ладно,    благодарю
Прошу прощения за тупость, только сел это все изучать

Comment: Могу только пожелать успехов. Прочтите про тернальный оператор и используйте выражение, которое я привел последним, всё должно заработать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте условие для максимума:

```
if (mas[i][j]%x == 0 && mas[i][j] > q)
```

И еще, я бы инициализировал `q` не нулем, а

```
q = INT_MIN;
```

Вдруг все числа будут отрицательны?